# Error in read txt file in R

Tags: r

I Had a text file but failed to load the data due to the following message

```
tnf100m <- read.fwf("100mM.txt", widths = c(12,9,13,31,3,13,11,25,10), header = FALSE, col.names = c("ID","time","wind", "Name","country","birth","heat","Location","date"),stringsAsFactors = F)

Error in substring(x, first, last) : 
          '<b1>0.0<20>   Usain Bolt                     JAM     21.08.86    1      Beijing                  16.08.2008'
```

The `100mM.txt` looks like the following:

```
1      9.58       +0.9   Usain Bolt    JAM     21.08.86    1      Berlin           16.08.2009
2      9.63       +1.5   Usain Bolt    JAM     21.08.86    1      London                   05.08.2012
3      9.69       ?0.0   Usain Bolt    JAM     21.08.86    1      Beijing                  16.08.2008
```

How to read the text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about changing the input values of `widths`?

I can read the file (a .txt file containing the text you provided) using `widths = c(1,10,11,13,7,13,5,14,27)`.

```
> read.fwf("D:/Users/perry/Downloads/100mM.txt", 
+          widths = c(1,10,11,13,7,13,5,14,27), 
+          header = FALSE, col.names = c("ID","time","wind", "Name","country","birth","heat","Location","date"), 
+          stringsAsFactors = F)
  ID time        wind          Name country         birth heat       Location                        date
1  1 9.58        +0.9    Usain Bolt     JAM      21.08.86    1       Berlin                    16.08.2009
2  2 9.63        +1.5    Usain Bolt     JAM      21.08.86    1       London                    05.08.2012
3  3 9.69        ?0.0    Usain Bolt     JAM      21.08.86    1       Beijing                   16.08.2008
```

Comment: Thank you. That helps and I cleaned up the data a bit.